# On complete of FB.getLoginStatus I want to return an array of information

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

this is my first time using the FB Dev JS and struggling a little.

Currently when I am trying to return an array of data I have been using alerts to test.

When I alert an item in my array, the alert comes up before the alert at the end of my FB.getLoginStatus function.

I cannot workout how to add a callback to this function.

How do I return data from FB.getLoginStatus?

Currently my setup is like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : '514297358660223',
        oauth   : true,
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

    // AFTER FB INIT
    // Get the status of the user
    var arrStatus = facebookLoginStatus();
    // IF the user is authorized, check to see whether they have voted.
    //alert(arrStatus[0]);
    if(arrStatus[0] != "error")
    {
        console.log("Check to see if they have voted");
        checkRegisteredVote(arrStatus[0]);
    }
    //
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
// END ::: Load the SDK Asynchronously

    function facebookLoginStatus()
{

    var userarr     = new Array(); 
    var strStatus   = "";
    var intUID      = 0;

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    {
        alert(response.status);
        if (response.status === 'connected')
        {
            strStatus   = "connected";
            intUID      = response.authResponse.userID;
            accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            userarr[0]  = userID;
            userarr[1]  = accessToken;
        }
        else
        {
            strStatus   = "not connected";
            userarr[0]  = "error";
            userarr[1]  = "not connected";
        }   


    }, true);

    alert(userarr[0]);

    return userarr;
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should move

```
 alert(userarr[0]);
```

3 lines above - INSIDE response function:

```
function(response) 
{
        if (response.status === 'connected')
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }   

        alert(userarr[0]);
}
```

also, that means that

```
return userarr;
```

is wrong - it will return something which is not initialize yet. Instead, after *alert(userarr[0]);*, you should call your other function, passing *userarr* as argument.